# Partitioning AWS Kinesis Firehose data to s3 by payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, partitioning, payload, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using AWS-Kinesis-Firehose to injest data to S3, and consume it afterwards with Athena.

I am trying to analyze events from different games, to avoid Athena explore much data I would like to partition the s3 data using an identifier for each game, so far I did not find a solution, as Firehose receives data from different games.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thank you, 
Javi.

Comment: it would be better to add the code you have so far

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate? Its a valid and very much different question. Its an error to mark it as duplicate. This question asks how to create custom partition based on value of the kinesis stream. The question supposed to be duplicate talks about parquet files, both are completely different. Kinesis can work without transformation too. Please remove duplicate mark.

Answer (score 3):

You could possibly use [Amazon Kinesis Analytics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/what-is.html) to split incoming Firehose streams into separate output streams based upon some logic, such as Game ID.

It can accept a [KinesisFirehoseInput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/API_KinesisFirehoseInput.html) and send data to a [KinesisFirehoseOutput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/API_KinesisFirehoseOutput.html).

However, the [limits documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/limits.html) seems to suggest that there can only be 3 output destinations per application, so this would not be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You could send your traffic to the main FireHose stream - then use a lambda function to split the data to multiple FireHose streams - one for each game that will save the data in a separate folder/bucket

Comment: I thought about this, but there is a problem, I expect to have around 20 Million daily events, that means that the lambda function will be triggered 20M times a day just to "classify" the events, that would be expensive.

Comment: I have found the cloudWatch events, that could help me by doing it in a time intervals, but still could be expensive

Comment: Lambda can be triggered as a batch up to 1000 events via FireHose - which will reduce your triggers dramatically

Comment: I have already done as you said before, by assigning a lambda function to a firehose stream, as I have configured a batch timing of 300 secs, it is enough to fill my needs. The batch upon events is not valid for me, as I can receive many events in a short period of time or a few, I do not want to wait until I have received 1000 events. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Please note that the batch setting is "up to X events" it will not hold your stream until it reached the limit